# selecting pulldown in htmlunit

Tags: java, jython, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit in jython and am having trouble selecting a pull down link. The page I am going to has a table with other ajax links, and I can click on them and move around and it seems okay but I can't seem to figure out how to click on a pulldown menu that allows for more links on the page(this pulldown affects the ajax table so its not redirecting me or anything).

Here's my code:

```
    selectField1 = page.getElementById("pageNumSelection")
options2 = selectField1.getOptions()
theOption3 = options2[4]
```

This gets the option I want, I verify its right.  so I select it:

```
MoreOnPage = selectField1.setSelectedAttribute(theOption3, True)
```

and I am stuck here(not sure if selecting it works or not because I don't get any message, but I'm not sure what to do next.  How do I refresh the page to see the larger list? When clicking on links all you have to do is find the link and then select linkNameVariable.click() into a variable and it works. but I'm not sure how to refresh a pulldown. when I try to use the webclient to create an xml page based on the the select variable, I still get the old page.

to make it a bit easier, I used htmlunit scripter and got some code that should work but its java and I'm not sure how to port it to jython. Here it is:

```
 try
      {
           page = webClient.getPage( url );

           HtmlSelect selectField1 = (HtmlSelect) page.getElementById("pageNumSelection");
           List<HtmlOption> options2 = selectField1.getOptions();
           HtmlOption theOption3 = null;
           for(HtmlOption option: options2)
           {
                if(option.getText().equals("100") )
                {
                     theOption3 = option;
                     break;
                }
           }
           selectField1.setSelectedAttribute(theOption3, true );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at HtmlForm  [getSelectedByName](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlForm.html#getSelectByName%28java.lang.String%29)

> HtmlSelect htmlSelect = form.getSelectByName("stuff[1].type");
>
> HtmlOption htmlOption = htmlSelect.getOption(3);
>
> htmlOption.setSelected(true);

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that [WebClient.setJavaScriptEnabled](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29) is called. The documentation seems to indicate that it is on by default, but I think this is wrong.

Alternatively, you can use [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted), which is a framework that supports both HtmlUnit and Selenium. I personally find the syntax easier to deal with than HtmlUnit.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the selection of an option in the select box triggers an AJAX calls which, once finished, modifies some part of the page.

The problem here is that since AJAX is, by definition, asynchronous, you can't really know when the call is finished and when you may inspect the page again to find the new content.

HtmlUnit has a class named [`NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController.html), which you can pass an instance of to the WebClient's [`setAjaxController`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#setAjaxController%28com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.AjaxController%29) method. As indicated in the javadoc, using this ajax controller will automatically make the asynchronous calls coming from a direct user interaction synchronous instead of asynchronous. Once the setSelectedAttribute method is called, you'll thus be able to see the changed made to the original page.

The other option is to use WebClient's [`waitForBackgrounfJavascript`](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html#waitForBackgroundJavaScript%28long%29) method after the selection is done, and inspect he page once the background JavaScript has ended, or the timeout has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer to the question because I've not used HtmlUnit much before, but you might want to look at [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), and in particular [Selenium RC](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). With Selenium RC you are able to control the interactions with a page displayed in a native browser (Firefox for example). It has developer API's for Java and Python amongst others.

I understand that HtmlUnit uses its own javascript and web browser rendering engine and I'm wondering whether that may be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bennettweb. I looked into Selenium but it didn't seem to be headless and I am running it in a headless linux enviorment.

Comment: You can still run Firefox in a headless mode on your linux headless environment by specifying a virtual display for it to connect to. You can then use WebDriver as mentions in some of the other answers to connect to Firefox.